# ListFragment onListItemClick - how to know which component is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout

The View Object is from `onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id)` is `RelativeLayout`.

However, I want to know which component inside the `RelativeLayout` is clicked as well for extended functionality.

How do I do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: This answer show why use recyclerview instead of Listview, I think recyclerview will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/2242903

Comment: @GustavoRozolin Thanks.

Comment: @GokhanArik do me a favour and read the question before commenting.

Comment: My bad. Adding answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a listener to every view in `RelativeLayout` you want to listen. If you want to use a single listener, create one and add it to all of the views you want to listen. In your `onClick` method, you can put `view.getId()` to switch statement and determine which one is clicked.

`OnItemClickListener` won't solve your problem. Neither switching to `RecyclerView`. They work the same way. It is all about your adapter. If you are using a **custom** adapter, it doesn't matter you use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. In your adapter, you have access to your components that are in your `RelativeLayout`. Create a listener as I explained above and add them to your views.

Not the same but similar question: [Android: Add event listeners to every item in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851802/android-add-event-listeners-to-every-item-in-a-listview)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

This answer show why use recyclerview instead of Listview, I think recyclerview will solve your problem stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/2242903

Comment: Bit complicated, and the lack of a fully working sample code with multiple components isn't nice... But thanks for pointing me at the right direction.

Comment: `ListView` and `RecyclerView` are similar. This won't solve his problem.

Comment: @GokhanArik did you read this anser stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/2242903 ?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is true, `RecyclerView` doesn't have `onItemClickListener` and it might be better to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. However, if he wants to use `ListView` he can still achieve the same thing. The answer you posted states that  'The moment you have a click listener for any of the internal elements the callback would not be triggered but it wasn't notified or well documented (if at all) so there was a lot of confusion and SO questions about it.' It was confusing but not impossible. You just have to add `focusable` attributes or block descendants.